# Adding data to a blank data frame based on column and index

Tags: pandas

I've created an empty data frame (df2) that has peoples names as the index and jobs as headers. I have (df1) which has data. I'd like to read from (df1) and input to (df2) based on header and index names. Kind of like index match match in Excel.

```
(df1)

    NAME      JOB    TIME
1   joe      job_1     1      
2   mike     job_2     4      
3   steve    job_3     5      
4   phil     job_4     2      
5   frank    job_5     8     


(df2)

       job_1  job_2  job_3  job_4  job_5
joe      0      0      0      0      0
mike     0      0      0      0      0
steve    0      0      0      0      0
phil     0      0      0      0      0
frank    0      0      0      0      0


(what I want df2)

       job_1  job_2  job_3  job_4  job_5
joe      1      0      0      0      0
mike     0      4      0      0      0
steve    0      0      5      0      0
phil     0      0      0      2      0
frank    0      0      0      0      8
```

Do I need to make the data in the TIME column a key for a dictionary?

Comment: How is pivoting and grouping a single data frame the same thing?

Comment: @ jezrael care to explain the marked as duplicate perhaps I'm missing the similarity?

Comment: Sure, is not necessary `df2`. But if really need it, add last `df = df.reindex(index = df2.index, columns=df2.columns, fill_value=o)`

Comment: Yes in this situation df2 is necessary, I need the zeros as I'm looking at when individuals arent performming certain jobs. I tried df1 = df1.reindex(index = df2.index, columns=df2.columns, fill_value=0) but its all zeros no data was filled from df1.

Comment: I think first need `df.set_index(['NAME', 'JOB'])['TIME'].unstack(fill_value=0)` and then `df = df.reindex(index = df2.index, columns=df2.columns, fill_value=0)`.

Comment: Gotcha now I see, thank you jezrael!